# SwiftUI design pattern - How to make a "2nd-stage" API call from the result of the first one

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

This is on iOS 15.5 using the latest SwiftUI standards.

I have these two structs in my SwiftUI application:

**User.swift**

```swift
struct User: Codable, Identifiable, Hashable {
    let id: String
    let name: String
    var socialID: String? // it's a var so I can modify it later

    func getSocialID() async -> String {
        // calls another API to get the socialID using the user's id
        // code omitted
        // example response:
        // {
        //     id: "aaaa",
        //     name: "User1",
        //     social_id: "user_1_social_id",
        // }        
    }
}
```

**Video.swift**

```swift
struct Video: Codable, Identifiable, Hashable {
    let id: String
    let title: String
    var uploadUser: User
}
```

My SwiftUI application displays a list of videos, the list of videos are obtained from an API (which I have no control over), the response looks like this:

```json
[
    {
        id: "AAAA",
        title: "My first video. ",
        uploaded_user: { id: "aaaa", name: "User1" },
    },
    {
        id: "BBBB",
        title: "My second video. ",
        uploaded_user: { id: "aaaa", name: "User1" },
    },
]
```

My video's view model looks like this:

**VideoViewModel.swift**

```swift
@MainActor
class VideoViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var videoList: [Video]

    func getVideos() async {
        // code simplified
        let (data, _) = try await URLSession.shared.data(for: videoApiRequest)
        let decoder = getVideoJSONDecoder()
            
        let responseResult: [Video] = try decoder.decode([Video].self, from: data)
        self.videoList = responseResult
    }

    func getSocialIDForAll() async throws -> [String: String?] {
        var socialList: [String: String?] = [:]
        
        try await withThrowingTaskGroup(of: (String, String?).self) { group in
            for video in self.videoList {
                group.addTask {
                    return (video.id, try await video.uploadedUser.getSocialId())
                }
            }
            
            for try await (userId, socialId) in group {
                socialList[userId] = socialId
            }
        }
        
        return socialList
    }
}
```

Now, I wish to fill in the `socialID` field for the `User` struct, which I must obtain from another API using each user's ID. the response looks like this for each user:

```json
{
    id: "aaaa",
    name: "User1",
    social_id: "user_1_social_id",
}
```

Right now the only viable way to get the information seems to be using `withThrowingTaskGroup()` and call `getSocialID()` for each user, which I am using right now, then I can return a dictionary that contains all the `socialID` information for each user, then the dictionary can be used in SwiftUI views.

But, is there a way for me to fill in the `socialID` field in the `User` struct without having to use a separate dictionary? It doesn't seem like I can modify the `User` struct in each `Video` inside `videoList` once the JSON decoder initializes the list of videos, due to the fact that `VideoViewModel` is a `MainActor`. I would prefer to have everything downloaded in one go, so that when the user enters a subview, there is no loading time.

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/72611881/12299030?

Comment: I don’t think a model object like User should contain functionality to fetch data from a rest api, that should be handled by a separate class.

Comment: Instead of returning a `Dictionary` from `getSocialIDForAll()`, why not just set the `socialID` when iterating through the video list?

Comment: I wrote an answer to show what I mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that you can't modify the structs once they are initialized, because all of their properties are `let` variables; however, you can modify the `videoList` in `VideoViewModel`, allowing you to dispense with the `Dictionary`.

```swift
@MainActor
class VideoViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var videoList: [Video]

    func getVideos() async {
        // code simplified
        let (data, _) = try await URLSession.shared.data(for: videoApiRequest)
        let decoder = getVideoJSONDecoder()
            
        let responseResult: [Video] = try decoder.decode([Video].self, from: data)
        self.videoList = try await Self.getSocialIDForAll(in: responseResult)
    }

    private static func updatedWithSocialID(_ user: User) async throws -> User {
        return User(id: user.id, name: user.name, socialID: try await user.getSocialID())
    }

    private static func updatedWithSocialID(_ video: Video) async throws -> Video {
        return Video(id: video.id, title: video.title, uploadUser: try await updatedWithSocialID(video.uploadUser))
    }

    static func getSocialIDForAll(in videoList: [Video]) async throws -> [Video] {
        return try await withThrowingTaskGroup(of: Video.self) { group in
            videoList.forEach { video in
                group.addTask {
                    return try await self.updatedWithSocialID(video)
                }
            }
    
            var newVideos: [Video] = []
            newVideos.reserveCapacity(videoList.count)
    
            for try await video in group {
                newVideos.append(video)
            }
    
            return newVideos
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot use `inout` here because this class is a `MainActor`. Also, for the record, I am willing to change those to `var`. ("Property 'videoList' isolated to global actor 'MainActor' can not be mutated from a non-isolated context")

Comment: Ah... there are still solutions that could use basically this same code.  Do you want to initialize the `socialID` when you call `getVideos()`?

Comment: That would be ideal, yes. One rudimentary approach I thought of was to somehow mash the JSONs together, but I thought there has to be something easier.

Comment: Well, one alternative is, instead of building a `Dictionary` like you are currently doing, build a new `[Video]`.   That's certainly the "functional" thing to do, but I'm often dealing with very large data, and an approach like that seems very wasteful.

Comment: If you're happy with your existing coupling of `User` with the API to get the `socialID`, you could implement your own `User.init(from: Decoder)` to call `getSocialID()` when the attempt to decode it is `nil`.   That would have to be a synchronous call though.

Comment: Updated my answer to work with `@MainActor` (at least it compiles - obviously I don't have your video API to try it for real).

Comment: Works really well, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Using a view model object is not standard for SwiftUI, it's more of a UIKit design pattern but actually using built-in child view controllers was better. SwiftUI is designed around using value types to prevent the consistency errors typical for objects so if you use objects then you will still get those problems. The View struct is designed to be the primary encapsulation mechanism so you'll have more success using the View struct and its property wrappers.

So to solve your use case, you can use the `@State` property wrapper, which gives the View struct (which has value semantics) reference type semantics like an object would, use this to hold the data that has a lifetime matching the View on screen. For the download, you can use async/await via the `task(id:)` modifier. This will run the task when the view appears and cancel and restart it when the `id` param changes. Using these 2 features together you can do:

```
@State var socialID

.task(id: videoID) { newVideoID in 
    socialID = await Social.getSocialID(videoID: newViewID)
}
```

The parent `View` should have a task that got the video infos.

Comment: I do understand what you mean here, however I want to put all the network requests at the beginning of a main view (the social ID is used in a sub-view) so that there is no loading when entering a sub-view.